# how to push img file and url input with js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, append, push

I'm trying to add a new item on an array that displays in a container on HTML. It's supposed to get an image file and an url from input, check the selected option and push each one to its specified array

Here is the relevant html:

```
<input type="file" name="comic-cover" id="comic-cover" required />
<input type="url" name="comic-url" id="comic-url" placeholder="url" required />

<select name="publisher-list" id="publisher">
                <option value="publisher" disabled>Publisher</option>
                <option value="dc">DC Comics</option>
                <option value="marvel">Marvel</option>
            </select>

<button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Add</button>

<h2 class="comic-publisher">DC Comics</h2>
        <div class="dc" id="block-dc">
        </div>

<h2 class="comic-publisher">Marvel</h2>
        <div class="marvel" id="block-marvel">
        </div>
```

and the js:

```
var comicCovers = ["imgs/Dark Knights of Steel-000.jpg", "imgs/Hawkeye-000.jpg"]
var trailers = ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WspmgrmEgn4", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssj0P0uY08U"]
var publishers = [0, 1];
var i = 0;
var blockDC = document.querySelector("#block-dc");
var blockMarvel = document.querySelector("#block-marvel");

render()

var publisher = document.querySelector("select").value;
document.querySelector("select") = function renderPublisher() {
    publisher = document.querySelector("select").value;
    return publisher;
}

// add new comics to the list // 
document.querySelector(".btn-submit") = function addOnList() {
    var newCover = document.querySelector("#comic-cover");
    var newTrailer = document.querySelector("#comic-url");

    if (newCover.endsWith(".jpg") & newTrailer.startsWith("https://")) {
        if (publisher == "dc") {
            publisher.push(0);
        } else {
            publisher.push(1)
        }

        comicCovers.push(newCover.value);
        trailers.push(newTrailer.value);
        newCover.value = "";
        newTrailer.value = "";
        render()
    }
}


function render() {
    for (i; i < comicCovers.length; i++) {
        // creates the comic covers using js var //
        var comicCover = document.createElement("img");
        comicCover.setAttribute("src", `${comicCovers[i]}`);

        // creates trailer button //
        var trailerButton = document.createElement("button");

        //  //
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        container.setAttribute("class", "container");
        container.appendChild(trailerButton);
        container.appendChild(comicCover);
        blockDC.appendChild(container);
        trailerButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Trailer"));
        trailerButton.setAttribute("class", "trailer-button");
        trailerButton.setAttribute("onclick", `openTrailer("${trailers[i]}")`);

        if (publishers[i] == 0) {
            blockDC.appendChild(container);
        } else {
            blockMarvel.appendChild(container);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use `if (newCover != "" & newTrailer != "")` and even changed the input type from file to url. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're tring to push values inside the variable called publisher which is just a string and not an array.

```
var publisher = document.querySelector("select").value;
publisher.push(0);
```

You're assigning a function to an html element by writing:

```
document.querySelector("select") = function renderPublisher() {
    publisher = document.querySelector("select").value;
    return publisher;
}
```

which is not correct.
Also The variables newCover and newTrailer are not strings.

```
 var newCover = document.querySelector("#comic-cover");
 var newTrailer = document.querySelector("#comic-url");
```

so you can't use the methods startsWith and endsWith for them, you have to access the elements' value instead. In order to get the name of the selected file you need to use the input tag's files attribute which returns an array of the selected files, we want the first file so we'll get the first item's name attribute.

```
 var newCover = document.querySelector("#comic-cover").value;
 var newTrailer = document.querySelector("#comic-url")?.files[0]?.name;
```

Overall first you need to grab the values provided inside the inputs, then push them inside the array related to the selected block(Marvel or DC), then you simply need to create the img, video and button tags and append them as a child to the selected block.
Url and file type validation should be handled also on both server and client side and it's gotta be much more than just checking if the fileName ends with ".jpg" or the url starts with "https://".
You need to store the uploaded image and video somewhere on the server. In order to do so, you'll have to attach an eventListener to the input tags so that whenever a file is selected, you'll send an upload request to the server, there you'll check if the file is valid and if so, you'll store the file somewhere on the server, then you'll pass the url of the uploaded photo/video as src to the img/video tags.

```js
const publishers = {
    dc: {
        comicCovers: [],
        trailers: []
    },
    marvel: {
        comicCovers: [],
        trailers: []
    }
}

const blockDC = document.querySelector("#block-dc");
const blockMarvel = document.querySelector("#block-marvel");
const blocksDivs = {
    dc: blockDC,
    marvel: blockMarvel
};

const addButton = document.querySelector(".btn-submit");
// add new comics to the list // 
addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const publisher = document.querySelector("#publisher").value;
    const newCoverFileName = document.querySelector("#comic-cover")?.files[0]?.name;
    const newTrailerUrl = document.querySelector("#comic-url").value;
    if (newCoverFileName?.endsWith(".jpg") && newTrailerUrl?.startsWith("https://")) {
        publishers[publisher].comicCovers.push(newCoverFileName);
        publishers[publisher].trailers.push(newTrailerUrl);
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        var coverImg = document.createElement("img");
        var playTrailerButton = document.createElement("button");
        playTrailerButton.innerHTML = "play trailer"
        coverImg.src = "http://yourserveraddress/imgs/" + newCoverFileName;
        //test photo
        coverImg.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300"
        container.appendChild(coverImg);
        container.appendChild(playTrailerButton);
        blocksDivs[publisher].appendChild(container);
        playTrailerButton.setAttribute("class", "trailer-button");
        playTrailerButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            var videoExists = document.getElementById(publishers[publisher].trailers.length)
            if (!videoExists) {
                var video = document.createElement('video');
                video.setAttribute("id", publishers[publisher].trailers.length)
                video.style.backgroundColor = "aliceblue"
                video.setAttribute("src", newTrailerUrl);
                video.setAttribute("width", "200")
                video.setAttribute("height", "200")
                container.appendChild(video);
                playTrailerButton.innerHTML = "close Trailer"
            } else {
                container.removeChild(videoExists)
                playTrailerButton.innerHTML = "play Trailer"
            }
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<input type="file" name="comic-cover" id="comic-cover" required />
<input type="url" name="comic-url" id="comic-url" placeholder="url" required />

<select name="publisher-list" id="publisher">
  <option value="publisher" disabled>Publisher</option>
  <option value="dc">DC Comics</option>
  <option value="marvel">Marvel</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Add</button>

<h2 class="comic-publisher">DC Comics</h2>
<div class="dc" id="block-dc">
</div>

<h2 class="comic-publisher">Marvel</h2>
<div class="marvel" id="block-marvel">
</div>
```